# Sumar Columnas de tablas diferentes en mysql

Tags: mysql, delphi, report

Estoy realizando un informe en Rave report en delphi xe7, pero tengo que sumar los totales de dos data band, lo cual intente realizarlo mediante un datatext con la propiedad sum pero simplemente me calcula los dos primeros. Lo que intento hacer ahora es sumarlos en una consulta antes de llegar al informe de modo que el resultado lo relfeje en un campo de la tabla mediante una consulta sql, probé la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
  cproveedores.estado,
  SUM(cproveedores.total) AS Total
FROM
  cproveedores
WHERE
  cproveedores.estado = 'pendiente'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  fact_dolar.estado,
  SUM(fact_dolar.importe_total) AS Dol
FROM
  fact_dolar
WHERE
  fact_dolar.estado = 'pendiente'
GROUP BY
  fact_dolar.estado
```

pero me devuelve dos columnas y el listado de totales, pero como hago para sumarlo todo en un solo registro o campo calculado? AYUDA por FAVOR!

Comment: Verifica que el tipo de dato que estas retornando es del mismo tipo en ambas consultas, Union debe tener el mismo numero de campos y deben ser del mismo tipo de dato.

Answer (score 0):

Lo consulta que has hecho la puedes utilizar de subconsulta para a partir de ella obtener los totales, algo como:

```
SELECT SUM(tbl.total) AS totales
FROM
    (SELECT 
      cproveedores.estado as concepto
      SUM(cproveedores.total) AS total
    FROM
      cproveedores
    WHERE
      cproveedores.estado = 'pendiente'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      fact_dolar.estado as concepto
      SUM(fact_dolar.importe_total) AS total
    FROM
      fact_dolar
    WHERE
      fact_dolar.estado = 'pendiente'
    GROUP BY
      fact_dolar.estado) AS tbl
```